# change() event is calling twice in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**FINAL EDIT:** I've solve the problem on replace the .change() with a .trigger('click'). Works perfectly.

Thanks all

**LAST EDIT:**
i've try to reproduce the problem on Jsfiddle, but it's work perfectly : https://jsfiddle.net/a8e0fmn0/9/

**EDIT:** (see new code) i've place some alert with Number, and when i execute, the result is :

when i click on #idModalCheckbox : 1-2-3-3

when i click on #idCheckbox : 3

**END EDIT**

-

I have 2 .change function, the 1st change the second, and the second generate a ajax request.

mycode.js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#modalCheckBox').on('change', '#idModalCheckbox', function(){
alert('1');
    var id = $(this).parents('#id');
                    $('#idList li').each(function() {
                        if($(this).children('#id').html() == id) {
alert('2');
    //loop to find the right row
                            item = $(this).find('#idListCheckBox').prop('checked', true).change();
                        }
                    });
                });

        $('#idCheckBox').change(function(){
alert('3');
            var oPost = {
                "1": a,
                "2": b,
                "3": c};
    //oPost get data from the $(this) row 






        console.log(oPost);
        $.ajax(
            {
                url : "http://" + d + e + f,
                data : oPost,
                type : 'post',
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(jsonCallback)
                {
                    console.log(jsonCallback);
                }
            });
        });
});
```

then in my console, i've 2 times my post and 2 times my JsonCallback when i click on '#idModalCheckbox' and i've just one times when i click on '#idCheckBox'

my.html (generate with loop in php, where my idCheckbox are)

```
<li>
    <span hidden id="id"><?=id;?></span>

    <span>
          <input id="idCheckBox" name="idCheckBox" <?= $checked == true ? 'checked': '';?> data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-width="60" data-size="small" type="checkbox" data-on="on" data-off="off"/>
   </span>
</li>
```

my2.html (modal) (generate with php in a loop)

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input id="modalCheckBox" name="modalCheckBox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-width="60" data-size="small" type="checkbox" data-on="on" data-off="off"/>


    </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: welcome to [so] please clarify your question

Comment: have you included your script more than once? I recently had a click event fire twice because I didn't realise I included my js script twice

Comment: can you post the html this is associated to?

Comment: when i click on the checkbox in my modal, i don't want 2 request, i just want change the other checkbox, and when the second is change, send my ajax request.

Comment: Are there two elements with `idModalCheckbox`?

Comment: Wait for the html

Comment: Nop, idModalCheckbox is unique, like idCheckbox

Comment: Are there multiple elements with `#idListCheckBox`? You are looping list items looking for them so it seems like there would be more than one.

Comment: You should ensure your IDs are unique - makes things much easier.

Comment: without the associated HTML it's hard to be sure what the root cause is. Even better, turn your question into a StackSnippet which actually reproduces the error.

Comment: i've add the "html" code

Comment: The `this` in this code `$('#idModalCheckbox').change(function() { $('#idList li').each(function() { item = $(this).find('#idListCheckBox').` refers to the `#idList li` which you *generate in a loop* therefore there are multiple `#idList li` (despite IDs must be unique) and you get multiple ajax calls.

Comment: Thx freedomn-m, so, it's not the problem because in this function, the code are execute just one times. (see the edit notes)

Comment: Open the page in your browser and post the HTML that the browser renders? Most likely there is more than 1 element with the same ID (which is invalid). You'll need to use classes (or a different selector method).

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML seems to contain a few problems

In the first code block

```
<li>
    <span hidden id="id"><?=id;?></span>

    <span>
          <input id="idCheckBox" name="idCheckBox" <?= $checked == true ? 'checked': '';?> data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-width="60" data-size="small" type="checkbox" data-on="on" data-off="off"/>
   </span>
   </span><!-- This tag doesn't have a matching opening tag -->
</li>
```

the last `</span>` tag is an orphan

in the second code snipper

```
<tr>
    <td> <!--                           below here, double quote -->
        <input id="modalCheckBox" name=""modalCheckBox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-width="60" data-size="small" type="checkbox" data-on="on" data-off="off"/>

    </td>
</tr>
```

Right after the `name` attribute you have a double double quote, which messes up your HTML

In your JavaScript where do the `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f` variables come from ?
If they are globals you should use `window.a` to make it explicit and avoid collisions

I do not see any double calls, which means I stil can not reproduce your bug.
Try fixing your HTML (whatever IDE you use should have a way to let you know when your HTML is invalid)

Can you provide a working code snipper like the one below where the bug can be reproduced ?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>
    <span id="id">2</span>

    <span>
          <input id="idCheckBox" name="idCheckBox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-width="60" data-size="small" type="checkbox" data-on="on" data-off="off"/>
   </span>
   </span>
</li>
</ul>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input id="modalCheckBox" name=""modalCheckBox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-width="60" data-size="small" type="checkbox" data-on="on" data-off="off"/>


    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In the example below, which is your code cleaned up and adapted to not need the unknown JavaScript vars, i do not see any double calling

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#modalCheckBox').on('change', '#idModalCheckbox', function()
    {
        var id = $(this).parents('#id');
        $('#idList li').each(function()
        {
            if($(this).children('#id').html() == id) 
            {
                //loop to find the right row
                item = $(this).find('#idListCheckBox').prop('checked', true).change();
            }
        });
    });

    $('#idCheckBox').change(function()
    {
        var oPost = 
        {
            "1": 11,
            "2": 12,
            "3": 13
        };
            //oPost get data from the $(this) row 

        console.log(oPost);
        $.ajax(
        {
            url : "http://",
            data : oPost,
            type : 'post',
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(jsonCallback)
            {
                console.log(jsonCallback);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
      <span id="id">2</span>

      <span>
        <input id="idCheckBox" name="idCheckBox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-width="60" data-size="small" type="checkbox" data-on="on" data-off="off"/>
      </span>
  </li>
</ul>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input id="modalCheckBox" name="modalCheckBox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-width="60" data-size="small" type="checkbox" data-on="on" data-off="off"/>


    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hello, thx for your answer, Sry but the code isn't the same, that's why the variable a,b,c,.. isn't here, like the same of error in HTML because it's generate with Php or JS.

Comment: Is your problem solved ? If not, are you willing to give us more information about what you tried and maybe the aplication's full source code ? If it is, please upvote the answere(s) that helped you and mark and tag one as the answer that solved your problem (the little check on the left of th answer). If the problem was fixed without using any of the answers in this thread, please answer your own question and tag yourself as "gave the answer to the question" so the topic gets closed

Comment: Nop, the problem isn't solved but i've add a jsfiddle on last edit, it's work perfectly, so i don't know why mine called 2 times the second function ..

Comment: Well then, this means that the code you gave us works. So it's something else. Your script isn't executed inside of a loop ? i'm thinking of the html and code being in a file, and you call that file multiple times (like displaying multiple sets of similar data). Could you provide us all of the complete files related to your problem ? Maybe a copy of the whole website if it isn't restricted by legal/moral/personal reasons ?

Answer (score 0):

You either binded the event twice or you binded it once to two elements that both have that id.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating `html` through `php loop` , and your code seems that `html`creating `html elements` with same `id's` , But `id` should be unique .

i think , please correct your html code .